# Dúvida com a API do Google Charts

Tags: google-charts

Tenho um gráfico de barras em meu sistema utilizando a API do google charts. Está em funcionamento já, porém estou com o seguinte problema. Apresento nos gráficos os valores recebidos e gastos mensais de janeiro a dezembro. Está apresentando todos os valores, porém, o problema está na apresentação dos números. Quando tenho o valor de R$ 1500,00 ele apresenta o valor 1.5. Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar para o formato de moeda nacional?

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Mês', 'Receitas', 'Custos e Despesas'],
                ['Janeiro', <?php echo $recebimentoJan; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoJan; ?>],
                ['Fevereiro', <?php echo $recebimentoFev; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoFev; ?>],
                ['Março', <?php echo $recebimentoMar; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoMar; ?>],
                ['Abril', <?php echo $recebimentoAbr; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoAbr; ?>],
                ['Maio', <?php echo $recebimentoMai; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoMai; ?>],
                ['Junho', <?php echo $recebimentoJun; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoJun; ?>],
                ['Julho', <?php echo $recebimentoJul; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoJul; ?>],
                ['Agosto', <?php echo $recebimentoAgo; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoAgo; ?>],
                ['Setembro', <?php echo $recebimentoSet; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoSet; ?>],
                ['Outubro', <?php echo $recebimentoOut; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoOut; ?>],
                ['Novembro', <?php echo $recebimentoNov; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoNov; ?>],
                ['Dezembro', <?php echo $recebimentoDez; ?>, <?php echo $pagamentoDez; ?>]
            ]);

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Evolução mensal do ano de '+<?php echo $ano; ?>+''
                },
                bars: 'vertical'            
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));         
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Tem como compartilhar o código?

Comment: Vou compartilhar o código:

Answer (score 2):

Na linha:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

Adicione:

```
'language': 'pt'
```

Fica assim:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart'],'language': 'pt'})
```

Na propriedade `hAxix`, adicione `format: 'currency',`

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente a API do google não converte a moeda para reais. Porém o que pode ser feito é a conversão através do próprio código. Assim você imprime o valor convertido acompanhado do símbolo da moeda nacional R$.
ex em PHP:

```
// repare que o padrão é no formato americano

echo 'R$' . number_format($num, 2); // retorna R$100,000.50


// nosso formato

echo 'R$' . number_format($num, 2, ',', '.'); // retorna R$100.000,50
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo, ele não gera o gráfico...

Comment: tenta isso então:    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
      {negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, pattern: '$###,###'});
   formatter.format(data, 1);  formatter.format(data, 1);

Comment: O gráfico também não aparece, que droga cara...

Comment: Poxa Gustavo, então não tenho muito mais ideia de como te ajudar =( espero que alguém responda. Fiquei curioso pra saber qual a solução agr.

Comment: Agradeço muito sua ajuda... Se encontrar uma solução, posto aqui... Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
//Insira o código "var formatter" nesse local:

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: 'R$ ', decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.' }); formatter.format(data, 0); formatter.format(data, 1);

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));         
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```